# How to do this in NODEJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, database-connection

This has no code as it is the middle of the night and woke up with a question.

I have a node.js web app and use firebase for auth username (email)
and password, there is also a Token which is an in app currency in the database. Lets say User1 has 50tokens in his account , and the tokens are saved in the fire base database, user 2 has 20 tokens in his database.

User 1 decides to send 20 tokens to User 2.

Is it possible to extract the amount 50 from the database subtract 20 and print the new value (20) tokens remaining and add to the User 2 20 tokens so in total he has now 40tokens saved in the database.

I also had the idea of creating a class and make it a wallet and store the tokens in the wallet, I have a rough idea how to do this, but where does the tokens value get stored? How can I establish a connection to add/subtract tokens between users?

If you were to do this? How would you do it?

Ps. Im not asking to write the code for me, I just really cant seem to find a solution in my head and its been bothering me to the point that I cant sleep. I will be trying recommendations from here and keep posting code snippets to see how well it performs and hope helps me and someone else in future.

Ps. Wallets are non crypto, just in app currency token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I can think of the uses cases I faced while dealing with such problems, the solution for deduction and transfer and credit is pretty straight forward as you might already have an idea.

But the key point of concern is how we handle failures, concurrency and overlapping transactions involving the same parties which were done in a tight period. This can complicate the simplistic transaction as the, in this case, the way you handle becomes important.

For such solutions where each transaction has to be atomic, and we cannot afford incomplete transactions, we would want a lossless and highly reproducible transactions based system.

Thus I would recommend CQRS ( Command Query Responsibility Segregation) pattern as this would help in performing rollbacks and retries for transactions. Also, it helps in consolidation and aggregation as well as verification for each transaction.

Thus an event-based system can raise independent events for each transaction which will be stored like transaction logs. These logs will then be picked up by your Transaction Processor which can be a function or module or service.

This service then can perform the relevant transactions of transfer of tokens and also raise analytics, verification and consolidation events.

As it is said a picture is worth a thousand words here's one for you.

[image]

PS- This is by no means a complete solution, but a general strategy to achieve the final solution. Also, there will be many other ways to get this done, but the above is based on my experience and way of thinking